# Custom ValidationMessageFor and type of error

Tags: c#, validation, custom-attributes

is there any way to validate using ModelState and model, to determine the type of error?

example:

[Required]

I wanted to make a custom ValidationMessageFor, and within it whether the error is [Required] or other type of error.

I am using DataAnnotations and CodeFirst.

Have is code from start implemetantion:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var Validacao = "";       
    if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name] != null)
    {   
        foreach (var erros in helper.ViewData.ModelState[((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name].Errors)
        {
            Validacao = Validacao + " *";
        }
    }            
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(Validacao);
}
```

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any validation attribute has [ErrorMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessage.aspx) property you can use to specify error message directly in attribute. Example:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "required error")]
[MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "max length error")]
```

Comment: there is no attribute for this? had thought up this solution, but I thought exisita something specific for it.

tks

Comment: You may try to create something similar to what you have started with or try to write some custom metadata provider attribute and use it next while rendering. Something like here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=687 . But solution I have provided initially seems the easiest for me for usual projects (it may be not if you have some specific requirements)